# TIdHTTP Post to API and save response as a .pdf file

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, idhttp

I'm calling an `API URL` with some `parameters` according to the documentation provided.

The way the API is set up, the response should be an auto-download of a `.pdf` file.

The parameters are:

- `number` - which stands for a 13 digit number that represents the unique file indicator in their system (example: 5277110610029)
- `username` and `user_pass` respectively - which stand for the login credentials to access the system
- `client_id` - which stands for a unique client ID associated with my account in their system
- `language` - where I indicate the language the file contents should be in (English or other of the available languages)

Documentation indicates it should be made as a `Post` request.

I have the following code:

```
var
FileName : string;
URL: String;
Params: TStringList;
memStream: TMemoryStream;
...

begin
FileName:= MainModule.PDFfileName + '.pdf';

 begin
 URL := 'https://someURL/view_integrated_pdf.php?';
 Params := TStringList.Create;
 memStream := TMemoryStream.Create;

  try
  Params.Add('number='+MainModule.number+'');
  Params.Add('username='+MainModule.User+'');
  Params.Add('client_id='+MainModule.clientID+'');
  Params.Add('user_pass='+MainModule.Pass+'');
  Params.Add('language=en');

  MainModule.IdHTTP.Post(URL, Params, memStream);

  finally
  memStream.SaveToFile(ServerModule.FilesFolderPath+'\pdfs\'+FileName);
  Params.Free;
  memStream.Free;

  end;
 end;

pdfForm.ShowModal();

end;
```

If I try the resulting `URL` and `parameters` in the browser - it auto-downloads the `pdf` file the API gives me with the name `numberParameter.pdf`

If I do it in Delphi using the provided code, 8 out of 10 times it saves a `pdf file` with a `1 KB Size` (normally it is between `32` and `100` for the successful file) and when I try to open it in the program using my `pdfForm` and subsequent `viewer`, the viewer throws an error `"Invalid PDF structure"`

- What am I doing wrong? / How do you properly save a Post requests that returns a .pdf file to download from the API?

**UPDATE**

As per the comments, opening up the 1kb resulting PDF in Notepad++ displays the contents as simply `Error username.`

This is puzzling since I checked and the username being passed is accurate + if I paste the exact same URL with parameter values filed, in the browser, it works perfectly and gives me the correct PDF.

- Is my code not the correct approach to Post and save the file being sent?

Comment: What's the response you get from the server? You can try open your saved file into some advanced text editor and see the contents.

Comment: @MiroslavPenchev In the delphi app after running code, nothing. The pdfForm pops up as a modal, which should display the pdf file - only it tell me its structure is invalid. Opening it on Windows using Adobe tells me it can't open it (plus the 1kb corresponding size).  Opening it up with Notepad++ (thanks for the suggestion - just tried) displays the file contents as Error username (which is false since I checked the username and pasting the same URL in the browser works). Guess the API instead of giving me the pdf contents simply writes the error message to the file.

Comment: so, most probably you get as result some HTML with error message/code. If that's the case - then your execution of POST request is not what the server expected and it gives you an error, not the PDF you expected.

Comment: @MiroslavPenchev Yes. But I'm not seeing any issues with my code (apart maybe from using the memStream?) would you agree?

Comment: @t1f That's irrelevant: the server can have issues unbound to how perfect your code or your request was - you have to expect negative responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I try the resulting `URL` and `parameters` in the browser - it auto-downloads the `pdf` file the API gives me with the name `numberParameter.pdf`

The only way to do that in a browser is to put the parameters in the URL's query component, eg:

```
https://someURL/view_integrated_pdf.php?number=...&username=...&client_id=...&user_pass=...&language=en
```

... and not in a `POST` body, as your code is doing. Also, a browser would send a `GET` request, not a `POST` request.  Unless you are filling in an HTML webform (ie `<form action="<URL>" method="POST" ...>`) and submitting it.  Is that what the API documentation says to do?

Since you did not provide any details from the documentation about what this server is actually expecting, we can't really tell you whether your code is correct or wrong.  But it does seem that your manual tests are contradicting what you claim the documentation says the server is expecting.

> If I do it in Delphi using the provided code, 8 out of 10 times it saves a pdf file with a 1 KB Size (normally it is between 32 and 100 for the successful file) and when I try to open it in the program using my pdfForm and subsequent viewer, the viewer throws an error "Invalid PDF structure"

From comments, you say your file is receiving a textual error message.  `TIdHTTP` would save such text to your `TMemoryStream` **ONLY IF** either:

- the HTTP server is **NOT** reporting an error at the HTTP level, ie it is sending the text message using an HTTP `2xx` success response. I *suspect* this is what is happening in your case. By default, if the server uses a *proper* HTTP error code, `TIdHTTP` will raise an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` containing the text message and **NOT** save the text to your `TMemoryStream` at all.
- the HTTP server **IS** reporting an error at the HTTP level, but you are using the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` and `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` flags together in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property. In which case, `TIdHTTP` would not raise `EIdHTTPProtocolException` and would instead save whatever data the server sends as-is to your `TMemoryStream`.

Since there is clearly no HTTP exception being raised, you will have to validate the server's response before you can use the downloaded data in your `pdfForm`, ie by looking at the `TIdHTTP.Response.ContentType` and/or `TIdHTTP.Response.ContentDisposition` property to know whether the server actually sent a PDF file or not.

> This is puzzling since I checked and the username being passed is accurate + if I paste the exact same URL with parameter values filed, in the browser, it works perfectly and gives me the correct PDF.

Well, for one thing, you have a typo in your code: the `numberr` field needs to be `number` instead.

Beyond that, putting the URL in a browser is NOT the same operation that your code is doing, so try changing your code to mimic what you are doing manually, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., IdGlobalProtocols, IdHTTP, IdURI;

...

var
  URL : string;
  memStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  // All parameters into the URI for a HTTP GET request
  URL := 'https://someURL/view_integrated_pdf.php'
       + '?number=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode(MainModule.number)
       + '&username=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode(MainModule.User)
       + '&client_id=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode(MainModule.clientID)
       + '&user_pass=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode(MainModule.Pass)
       + '&language=en';

  memStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    MainModule.IdHTTP.Get(URL, memStream);

    // Is it really PDF? Other formats such as plaintext is not wanted.
    if not IsHeaderMediaType(MainModule.IdHTTP.ContentType, 'application/pdf') then Exit;

    memStream.SaveToFile(ServerModule.FilesFolderPath + '\pdfs\' + MainModule.PDFfileName + '.pdf');
  finally
    memStream.Free;
  end;

  pdfForm.ShowModal;
end;
```

If that does not work, then please update your question to provide the actual documentation.

Comment: Not sure if you know: ["i.e." and "e.g." versus "ie" and "eg"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/407288)

Comment: @AmigoJack yes, I do.  And I prefer the way I write it

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I can confirm I am not using the two options you mentioned in HTTPOptions, your 1st scenario seems to be the case. The `numberr` was a typo from one of my paste edits, nice catch though. The API documentation is in my native language and for that particular section it simply states the base url, the required parameters and the fact that it should be called with HTTP POST. Upon succesful call it indeed should be serving a pdf file. The confusion was mine, as you pointed out, by believing a browser identical call (GET) would validate my POST code as well.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Seems to work fine it I use GET instead of POST in my code (thanks for your example!). Consequently, I’ll assume the documentation is faulty and they really meant GET, not POST. Just checked and noticed every method in the documentation is marked as requiring a POST, no GET, PUT, etc. Hence, seems like a faulty copy paste. I’ll try to clarify with them. Thank you again!